# Comparison between register and ascii character

Tags: assembly, compare, ascii, mips

In mips assembly,how can i compare the content of a register (byte- i have used lb command) with a character based on ASCII table ? is it correct to use beq $t0,45,L1 , where 45 the decimal number for the character

Comment: Any decent assembler would allow you to write `beq $t0,'-',L1`

Comment: in case we can't use the ' ' ? i mean how can we compare with the demical number

Comment: Then look it up in an ascii table.

Comment: the assembler we use doesn't assemble it - syntax error that's why i am asking!

Answer (score 2):

The principle is correct, but if there is a syntax error, you can load the character code in a register and compare the registers:

```
li $t1, 45
beq $t0, $t1, L1
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I think will help is for you to forget any notions of data types. Because computers aren't that smart.

You're asking whether you can compare $t0 with the decimal value 45 - well, of course you **can't**. The MIPS processor doesn't know anything about the decimal value 45. It only knows about two digits: 1 and 0. Fortunately, the decimal value 45 can be expressed as a bunch of 1s and 0s - `0010 1101` to be precise, in 8 bits.

Then, you're wondering whether you can compare $t0 with the ASCII character '-'. The MIPS processor doesn't know any more about ASCII characters than it does about decimal numbers. Fortunately, the [ASCII standard](http://www.asciitable.com/) doesn't say "this is a dash". It says that the character '-' maps to the bit pattern `0010 1101`, which we know as decimal 45. Or hex 0x2D - but the processor doesn't know anything about hex, either.

Here's where you really get lucky. You don't have to write your MIPS code in 1's and 0's. You could, but you don't have to - at least not once you've completed that particular homework assignment. :) Some smart dudes wrote something called an Assembler that turns characters you type (such as `beq $t0, 45, L1`) into one or more sets of 32 binary digits. And if the dudes were really smart, they would have probably made sure the Assembler knows that 45 is the same thing as 0x2D, and that's also the same thing as the ASCII character '-'.

(But yeah... like @Konrad said, shouldn't you have run the code through an assembler like MARS first?)

Edit: as @Patrik noted, `beq` takes two *registers*, not a register and an immediate. So of course you would get a syntax error with `beq $t0, 45, L1`. You would first need to load the value 45 into another register (perhaps $t8) and then `beq $t0, $t8, L1`.

Comment: thanks for the answer,firstly. Secondly, the assembler we use finds a syntax error in commands : $t0,45,L1  , $t0,'-',L1 , $t0,00101101,L1

Comment: @user3185493 Look at @Patrik's answer. I should have remembered, `beq` takes two *register* operands, not a register and an immediate. So you need to load your check value into a register and then compare.